# Why is my command block's /music command not playing my custom music?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’m a little confused and been at this for 2 days. I’m trying to make custom music I’ve uploaded. (Already did that part and works good)

But whenever I place a command block down and put in the command `/music play calm3 1 1 loop` for instance, nothing plays even though I get a message saying “calm 3 queued to start playing” and I sit for 5-6 minutes of silence for nothing.

What am I doing wrong? What’s the exact command format to get background music playing for all near players and how do I set it to loop until they activate another music command block?

Comment: Does `/music play music.game.calm3 1 1 loop` work? As far as I can tell from the Minecraft Wiki, you need to specify the full path of the music file.